I can't scrape from this website. Is it because the data is dynamic?
I am trying to scrape the data in the table at https://newtin.co811.org/responsedisplay/?ticket=B420800874 This website has different information for each ticket I don't know if it is the website or if I am not using beautiful soup correctly with the code. I am new to coding so I don't know a lot of the setups for the arguments.
This is what I am trying to do. I receive a excel file with a bunch of ticket numbers. I have to copy and past the ticket number into this website for every damn ticket to get the ticket info. It takes hours. I am trying to build an app that I load the excel spreadsheet and it opens the website with the ticket number and extracts the data and posts it into a spreadsheet so I can quickly look at all of the information. I can only get the program to pull in the ticket and response rows but not the data underneath.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import os

# Define function to extract data from website
def get_ticket_data(ticket_number):
    # Remove the last 4 characters from the ticket number
    ticket_without_last_4 = ticket_number[:-4]
    
    # Build URL
    url = f"https://newtin.co811.org/responsedisplay/?ticket={ticket_without_last_4}"
    
    # Send HTTP request to get the webpage content
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the page content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # Extract specific data from the page using CSS selectors
        # Update these selectors according to the webpage structure
        div1_data = soup.select_one("div.some-class-for-div1").text.strip() if soup.select_one("div.some-class-for-div1") else "N/A"
        div3_data = soup.select_one("div.some-class-for-div3").text.strip() if soup.select_one("div.some-class-for-div3") else "N/A"
        
        return {"Div1": div1_data, "Div3": div3_data}
    else:
        return {"Div1": "Error", "Div3": "Error"}

# Function to handle spreadsheet display and writing
def process_excel_file(input_data, output_filename):
    # Create a list to store scraped data
    data_list = []

    # Iterate through each row of input data
    for index, row in input_data.iterrows():
        ticket = row['Ticket']
        # Get data from website for each ticket
        web_data = get_ticket_data(ticket)
        
        # Append combined row and web data to the list
        data_list.append({
            "Ticket": ticket,
            "Account": row['Account'],
            "Completed": row['Completed'],
            "Work Date": row['Work Date'],
            "Type": row['Type'],
            "Category": row['Category'],
            "Priority": row['Priority'],
            "Company Name": row['Company Name'],
            "Web Div1": web_data['Div1'],
            "Web Div3": web_data['Div3']
        })

    # Convert the collected data into a DataFrame for easy manipulation
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    
    # Display the DataFrame in the console
    print(output_df)

    # Show the dataframe in the UI (optional for a basic UI)
    # For now, we'll display the first 5 rows
    messagebox.showinfo("Data Preview", f"First 5 rows:\n{output_df.head().to_string(index=False)}")
    
    # Save the file using the filename chosen by the user
    output_df.to_excel(output_filename, index=False)
    messagebox.showinfo("Save Complete", f"File saved as {output_filename}")

# Load your existing Excel file using file dialog
def load_file():
    # Open a file dialog to choose an Excel file
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
    
    if file_path:
        try:
            # Load the selected Excel file
            input_df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
            
            # Ask for save location and file name
            output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
            
            if output_file:
                # Process and display the data
                process_excel_file(input_df, output_file)
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Save Error", "Please specify a valid file name to save.")
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("File Error", f"Failed to load file.\nError: {e}")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("No File", "No file selected.")

# Basic UI setup
def main():
    # Create the main window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Ticket Data Scraper")

    # Window size
    root.geometry("300x150")
    
    # Add a button to load an Excel file
    load_button = tk.Button(root, text="Load Excel File", command=load_file)
    load_button.pack(pady=20)
    
    # Run the UI loop
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  It's also worth noting that, yes, if the content on the target website is dynamically written to the page then you may need to use a tool like Selenium instead.

The easy way to tell if the data is dynamic is to use View Source in the browser. That will show you the HTML that requests.get() returns. If you don't see the elements you're trying to find with BS, it's generated dynamically.

You don't see any data because the data is loaded with JavaScript from different URL dynamically. So beautifulsoup doesn't see it.
You can use next example to load the data in Json form:
import json
import requests


def get_ticket_data(ticket):
    url = f"https://newtin-api.co811.org/api/tickets/{ticket}/responses?all=true"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    return data


ticket = "B420800874"
data = get_ticket_data(ticket)

# pretty print the data
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

Prints:
{
    "ticket": "B420800874",
    "revision": "00B",
    "completed": "2024-07-26T18:31:30.553Z",
    "type": "NEW",
    "priority": "NORM",
    "category": "LREQ",
    "lookup": "STRT",
    "original_ticket": "B420800874",
    "original_date": "2024-07-26T18:31:30.553Z",
    "original_account": "WOODNW",
    "original_channel": "WEB",
    "replace_by_date": "2024-08-30T05:59:00.000Z",
    "expires": "2024-08-25T18:31:30.000Z",
    "reference": " ",
    "account": "WOODNW",
    "channel": "WEB",
    "started": "2024-07-26T18:31:21.553Z",
    "caller_type": "NONR",
    "name": "NW ENTERPRISES GROUP LLC",
    "address1": "19805 S LAKE DR",
    "city": "CLAREMORE",
    "cstate": "OK",
    "zip": "74017",
    "phone": "8122131230",
    "phone_ext": " ",
    "caller": "JACOB WOOD",
    "caller_phone": "8122131230",
    "contact": "MARKO RUIS HERNANDEZ",
    "contact_phone": "5039171838",
    "fax": " ",
    "email": "CO-Tickets@metronet.com",
    "secondary_excavator": " ",
    "secondary_contact": " ",
    "secondary_phone": " ",
    "secondary_phone_ext": " ",
    "secondary_email": " ",
    "state": "CO",
    "county": "EL PASO",
    "place": "CIMARRON HILLS",
    "st_from_address": "1998",
    "st_to_address": "1998",
    "street": "TEE POST LN",
    "cross1": "MEADOWBROOK PKWY",
    "latitude": " ",
    "longitude": " ",
    "legal": "Y",
    "work_date": "2024-07-31T13:00:00.000Z",
    "work_end": "2024-07-31T13:00:00.000Z",
    "duration_days": 0,
    "locate_by": "2024-07-31T05:59:00.000Z",
    "response_due": "2024-07-31T05:59:00.000Z",
    "hours_notice_clock": 107,
    "hours_notice_business": 59,
    "work_type": "BORING TO INSTALL FIBER OPTICS",
    "done_for": "CB-METRONET-COCH012",
    "reason_for_resend": " ",
    "extent_top": 38.858641,
    "extent_left": -104.677599,
    "extent_bottom": 38.857706,
    "extent_right": -104.676457,
    "area_in_miles": 0.003002,
    "blasting": false,
    "boring": true,
    "meet": false,
    "legal_notice": true,
    "request_01": false,
    "emergency": false,
    "damage": false,
    "response_required": true,
    "location": "SEE FILE ATTACHMENTS\nLOC REAR UTILITY EASE OF ADDRESS\nPLACE FLAGS ON ALL LOCATES\nCONTR CONTACT - MARKO RUIS HERNANDEZ 503-917-1838 - CALL WITH ANY QUESTIONS\n *ACCESS OPEN*\nMAP ATTACHED AS DIGITAL WHITE LINE",
    "remarks": null,
    "comments": null,
    "bestfit_y1": 38.85824,
    "bestfit_x1": -104.677746,
    "bestfit_y2": 38.858889,
    "bestfit_x2": -104.677085,
    "bestfit_y3": 38.85811,
    "bestfit_x3": -104.67632,
    "bestfit_y4": 38.857462,
    "bestfit_x4": -104.676981,
    "centroid_y": 38.858175,
    "centroid_x": -104.677032,
    "responses": [
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T21:14:12.193Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "004",
            "description": "NO ACCESS, GATE OR FENCE, NEW TICKET REQUESTED",
            "url": "https://ticketprocluster.usicllc.com/attachments_pdf?activity_id=1574352251&ticket=6PzunQD2eKlhNkUW1yzkyQ%3D%3D",
            "comments": "2024/07/31 15:12 Knocked on door and rang door bell no one answered door. No access to rear of lot, no Fence gate to access.",
            "mbcode": "CCSOCO01",
            "name": "COMCAST",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "COMCAST"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T03:06:19.690Z",
            "response_by": "Cameron Thomas (",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "Please contact USIC Customer Service at (800) 778-9140 or USICDispatch@usicllc.com for further info.",
            "mbcode": "CCSOCO01",
            "name": "COMCAST",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "COMCAST"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T03:06:01.320Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": "https://ticketprocluster.usicllc.com/attachments_pdf?activity_id=1573842453&ticket=6PzunQD2eKlhNkUW1yzkyQ%3D%3D",
            "comments": "Please contact USIC Customer Service at (800) 778-9140 or USICDispatch@usicllc.com for further info.",
            "mbcode": "CCSOCO01",
            "name": "COMCAST",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "COMCAST"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-26T22:14:26.270Z",
            "response_by": "TMS:DBROWN",
            "response": "002",
            "description": "CLEAR - NO CONFLICT",
            "url": null,
            "comments": null,
            "mbcode": "CHKWS1",
            "name": "CHEROKEE METROPOLITAN DISTRICT",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "cherokee METROPOLITAN DISTRICT"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-26T18:40:57.777Z",
            "response_by": "Default User",
            "response": "002",
            "description": "CLEAR - NO CONFLICT",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "No PW assets in work area",
            "mbcode": "CSPPW1",
            "name": "CITY OF COLORADO SPRINGS - PUBLIC WORKS",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "CITY OF COLORADO SPRINGS - PUBLIC WORKS"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-29T12:19:20.443Z",
            "response_by": "Steve R",
            "response": "002",
            "description": "CLEAR - NO CONFLICT",
            "url": null,
            "comments": null,
            "mbcode": "CSPU00",
            "name": "COLORADO SPRINGS UTILITIES",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "COLORADO SPRINGS UTILITIES"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-26T21:57:50.033Z",
            "response_by": "Trent Ortiz",
            "response": "002",
            "description": "CLEAR - NO CONFLICT",
            "url": "https://utilisync-docs.s3.amazonaws.com:443/1b28a286-f552-4d7f-83bf-2b8fd545d685/2e9b9b88-ead7-4ecc-9fa1-66f5ee4c9150.pdf",
            "comments": "b'No applicable EPC SW or TL located in the locate area.'",
            "mbcode": "ELPASOPW",
            "name": "EL PASO COUNTY DEPT. OF PUBLIC WORKS",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "EL PASO COUNTY DEPT. OF PUBLIC WORKS"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T21:14:10.717Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "004",
            "description": "NO ACCESS, GATE OR FENCE, NEW TICKET REQUESTED",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "2024/07/31 15:12 Knocked on door and rang door bell no one answered door. No access to rear of lot, no Fence gate to access.",
            "mbcode": "MVEL02",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN view ELECTRIC association"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T21:14:08.277Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "004",
            "description": "NO ACCESS, GATE OR FENCE, NEW TICKET REQUESTED",
            "url": "https://ticketprocluster.usicllc.com/attachments_pdf?activity_id=1574352250&ticket=6PzunQD2eKlhNkUW1yzkyQ%3D%3D",
            "comments": "2024/07/31 15:12 Knocked on door and rang door bell no one answered door. No access to rear of lot, no Fence gate to access.",
            "mbcode": "MVEL02",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN view ELECTRIC association"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T03:29:01.310Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": "https://ticketprocluster.usicllc.com/attachments_pdf?activity_id=1573846072&ticket=6PzunQD2eKlhNkUW1yzkyQ%3D%3D",
            "comments": "Please contact USIC Customer Service at (800) 778-9140 or USICDispatch@usicllc.com for further info.",
            "mbcode": "MVEL02",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN view ELECTRIC association"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T03:29:00.777Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "Please contact USIC Customer Service at (800) 778-9140 or USICDispatch@usicllc.com for further info.",
            "mbcode": "MVEL02",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN view ELECTRIC association"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T21:14:10.693Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "004",
            "description": "NO ACCESS, GATE OR FENCE, NEW TICKET REQUESTED",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "2024/07/31 15:12 Knocked on door and rang door bell no one answered door. No access to rear of lot, no Fence gate to access.",
            "mbcode": "MVELFBR",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC."
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T21:14:10.537Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "004",
            "description": "NO ACCESS, GATE OR FENCE, NEW TICKET REQUESTED",
            "url": "https://ticketprocluster.usicllc.com/attachments_pdf?activity_id=1574352249&ticket=6PzunQD2eKlhNkUW1yzkyQ%3D%3D",
            "comments": "2024/07/31 15:12 Knocked on door and rang door bell no one answered door. No access to rear of lot, no Fence gate to access.",
            "mbcode": "MVELFBR",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC."
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T03:20:02.347Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": "https://ticketprocluster.usicllc.com/attachments_pdf?activity_id=1573844444&ticket=6PzunQD2eKlhNkUW1yzkyQ%3D%3D",
            "comments": "Please contact USIC Customer Service at (800) 778-9140 or USICDispatch@usicllc.com for further info.",
            "mbcode": "MVELFBR",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC."
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T03:19:59.817Z",
            "response_by": "USIC",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "Please contact USIC Customer Service at (800) 778-9140 or USICDispatch@usicllc.com for further info.",
            "mbcode": "MVELFBR",
            "name": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC.",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "MOUNTAIN VIEW ELECTRIC ASSOC., INC."
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T21:14:19.353Z",
            "response_by": "Cameron Thomas (",
            "response": "004",
            "description": "NO ACCESS, GATE OR FENCE, NEW TICKET REQUESTED",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "2024/07/31 15:12 Knocked on door and rang door bell no one answered door. No access to rear of lot, no Fence gate to access.",
            "mbcode": "QLNCC00",
            "name": "CENTURYLINK",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "century link"
        },
        {
            "revision": "00B",
            "responded": "2024-07-31T01:14:25.353Z",
            "response_by": "CPM Automation 7",
            "response": "008",
            "description": "CALL FACILITY OWNER FOR FURTHER INFO ON LOCATE",
            "url": null,
            "comments": "Please contact our ticket management team if you need additional support at (877)-366-8344.",
            "mbcode": "QLNCC00",
            "name": "CENTURYLINK",
            "status": "RESPONDED",
            "phonetic": "century link"
        }
    ]
}


That is awesome and pretty much what I need for this application.  I will work out what else I need to do because the amount of data is incredible and doesn't even show on the website.  Thanks for your help!
